# How to rank and display side by side

Tags: t-sql

How to write a SQL query to display the output as shown below in 'Desired Output'.The value must be ranked in descending order within each type and displayed side-by-side.

```
Type    Cono    Value
1       100    66.5
1       123    65.6
1       145    56.8
2       145     6
2       100     7
2       123     8
```

Desired Output:

```
Rank    Cono    A-value Rank    Cono    B-value
 1     100      66.5    1        123     8
 2     123      65.6    2        100     7
 3     145      56.8    3        145     6
```

This is what I tried,

```
;with cte as
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by type order by value desc) Rank,*
  from temp1
)



select
max(CASE when Rank = 1 then rank end) as 'Rank',
max(CASE when Rank = 1 then cono end) as 'Cono',
max(CASE when Rank = 1 then display_value end) as 'A-days',
max(CASE when Rank = 2 then cono end) as 'Rank',
max(CASE when Rank = 2 then cono end) as 'cono'
max(CASE when Rank = 2 then display_value end) as 'B-days'

from cte
group by RANK,cono,value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly because it seems that the desired output doesn't correspond to the sample data so I might be missing something; but this query, or one very similar, should work:

```
 select t1.rank, t1.Cono, t1.value 'A-value', t2.rank, t2.Cono, t2.value 'B-value'
 from
 (select *,row_number() over (order by value desc) rank from temp1 where type=1) t1
 join 
 (select *,row_number() over (order by value desc) rank from temp1 where type=2) t2
 on t1.rank=t2.rank
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the data confusion - I corrected it.